# Ошибка 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программирую на Python 3 не очень давно. Хотел попробовать сделать текстовую игру, используя ООП. Сейчас пытался сделать движение вперед в двумерном мире, но он мне выдает ошибку `'method' object is not subscriptable`. Здесь представлена часть кода, из за которой ошибка появляется. Объясните, пожалуйста, что за ошибка и как ее исправить.

```
from math import sqrt

class Hero:

    coordinate = []

    def step_forward(self):
        self.coordinate[0] = self.coordinate[0] + 1
        return self.coordinate

hero = Hero()

enemy_hero = Hero()

hero.coordinate = [0, 0]

enemy_hero.coordinate = [20, 0]

while True:

    distance = sqrt( (enemy_hero.coordinate[0] - hero.coordinate[0])**2 + (enemy_hero.coordinate[1] - hero.coordinate[1])**2)

    hero.coordinate = hero.step_forward
```

Текст ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 21, in <module>
    distance = sqrt( (enemy_hero.coordinate[0] - hero.coordinate[0])**2 + (enemy_hero.coordinate[1] - hero.coordinate[1])**2)
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этой строке:

```
hero.coordinate = hero.step_forward
```

вы не вызываете метод, а записываете "ссылку" на метод в переменную. При следующей итерации цикла вы пытаетесь сделать `hero.coordinate[0]` по сути от ссылки на метод, о чем и говорится в ошибке. Вам просто нужно исправить данную строку на

```
hero.coordinate = hero.step_forward()
```

А вообще, по логике, метод `.step_forward()` должен менять координаты объекта, а не возвращать значение. Ваш код и меняет координаты объекта, и возвращает новое значение, которое вы потом еще раз записываете в поле с координатами объекта. Вам в принципе можно просто убрать `return` в методе `step_forward()` или никак не использовать значение, возвращенное из `step_forward()`. Вообще, лучше не менять вручную координаты объекта, обращаясь к ним снаружи, а делать это внутри методов.

Класс лучше реализовать так:

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, coordinate)
        # Если вы будете использовать один и тот же список с координатами для разных объектов, лучше при инициализации делать копию списка с помощью list
        self.coordinate = list(coordinate)

    def step_forward(self):
        self.coordinate[0] = self.coordinate[0] + 1
```

Тогда при создании объекта нужно будет еще указывать его координаты.

```
hero = Hero([0, 0])

enemy_hero = Hero([20, 0])

while True:

    distance = sqrt( (enemy_hero.coordinate[0] - hero.coordinate[0])**2 + (enemy_hero.coordinate[1] - hero.coordinate[1])**2)

    hero.step_forward()
```

`distance` тоже можно сделать методом того же класса:

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, coordinate)
        self.coordinate = list(coordinate)

    def step_forward(self):
        self.coordinate[0] = self.coordinate[0] + 1

    def distance(self, other):
        return sqrt( (other.coordinate[0] - self.coordinate[0])**2 + (other.coordinate[1] - self.coordinate[1])**2)
```

Тогда цикл будет выглядеть так:

```
while True:
    distance = hero.distance(enemy_hero)
    hero.step_forward()
```